# gnuplot to plot histogram with lines

Tags: line, gnuplot, histogram

I've two column data as:

```
9   17.52
11  29.77
7   62.75
11  36.15
7   30.46
7   52.5
9   65.26
9   90.05
14  101.87
12  86.88
15  74.78
```

And want that first column be plotted as histogram according to index of y2, and second column be plotted as line according to index of y1. Anyone has ideas?

Comment: the data are:
9    17.52;
11   29.77;
7    62.75; 
11   36.15;

Comment: What are y1 and y2? The names of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand your question correctly, but are you possibly looking for something like this:

```
set style fill solid border -1
set boxwidth 0.4

plot "Data.dat" u 2 w boxes t "boxes", "" u (column(0)):1 t "lines" w l
```

?